# Keras CNN prediction output is only predicting within a range of numbers

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, regression

I am trying to predict 3D medical brain images based on their assessment score using CNN, **however the accuracy scores I have received were within a range of numbers (ex: there are 7 possible test scores: 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5 and the output only gives predictions within 1-1.5 range)**

I have resized, normalized, and separated the images into train (66 imgs), test (22 imgs), and validation (22 imgs) sets. Because there are so few images, I have added a custom 3D image augmentation (from github) so the total number of images increased to 10x what I originally had.

I have tried changing most, if not all, the parameters (batch size, optimizer, learning rate, simpler/complex nn's, activation, loss, etc) within my network to no avail. I have also looked online for similar problems in hope that someone has had the same issue and solved it.

Here is an example image that I am using:

[image: image description]

the size of this image is (96, 96, 96) and a strip of its array value is (after normalizing them):

```
[0.54124768 0.59549533 0.61464823 0.59833751 0.50441322 0.33578409
 0.40528049 0.4359369  0.39544678 0.32074109 0.20008253 0.28538722
 0.27870766 0.37098099 0.13504691 0.2372147  0.4171059  0.56398624
 0.38187722 0.71896363 0.44387385 0.41523819 0.31195372 0.10586056
 0.12634818 0.13454185 0.57811427 0.6465261  0.61814963 0.61493715]
```

After preprocessing steps, I fed this into my CNN model:

```
batch_size = 3

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv3D(32, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_size))
model.add(Conv3D(32, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv3D(64, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(64, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv3D(128, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(128, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(128, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv3D(256, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(256, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv3D(256, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = customImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.2,
                                         zoom_range=0.2,
                                         horizontal_flip=True)

val_datagen = customImageDataGenerator()

test_datagen = customImageDataGenerator()



training_set = train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

validation_set = val_datagen.flow(x_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

testing_set = test_datagen.flow(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)



earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30)

history = model.fit(
                    training_set,
                    steps_per_epoch = len(x_train)//batch_size,
                    epochs = 50,
                    #callbacks = [earlystop],
                    validation_data = validation_set,
                    validation_steps = len(x_val)//batch_size
                    )
```

I created a custom accuracy check to visualize the outputs which are:

```
Predicted score: [1.8405123] True score: 3.0
Predicted score: [1.4033222] True score: 3.0
Predicted score: [1.4690828] True score: 1.0
Predicted score: [1.5127727] True score: 3.0
Predicted score: [1.6159409] True score: 1.0
Predicted score: [1.4333361] True score: 1.5
Predicted score: [1.7470968] True score: 3.0
Predicted score: [1.2196972] True score: 1.5
Predicted score: [1.5940914] True score: 4.0
Predicted score: [1.4052064] True score: 1.0
Predicted score: [1.5127727] True score: 1.0
Predicted score: [1.4584785] True score: 1.0
Predicted score: [1.7860543] True score: 3.0
Predicted score: [1.4752649] True score: 2.5
Predicted score: [1.8568267] True score: 1.0
Predicted score: [1.4793051] True score: 3.0
Predicted score: [1.395096] True score: 2.5
Predicted score: [1.6011616] True score: 4.0
Predicted score: [1.9094267] True score: 1.0
Predicted score: [1.6322718] True score: 1.0
Predicted score: [1.7284409] True score: 4.0
Predicted score: [1.5262214] True score: 1.5
Out: 0.09090909090909091
```

As you can see, the predicted values fall within the 1-2 range even though there are test scores at the 2.5, 3, 4, and 5 range.

```
print(y_pred.min(), y_pred.max())
1.2196972 1.9094267
```

Finally, here are my graphs:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the loss decreases beautifully, but the accuracy freezes midway and I am not sure what the cause may be.

Sorry for the long post, but I would appreciate any answers, thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that may help with the accuracy of your model.

1. Add BatchNomalization after each Conv3D layer, it improves the convergence.
2. Try scaling scores into a range [0, 1]. This is usually not a problem when you have enough data, but may become a problem if your dataset is small. This will also require a `softmax` activation in your last layer.
3. Dropout of 0.5 may be a bit extreme. Try adding a smaller dropout after each Conv3D. It can be conveniently combined with proposition 1) using the following wrapper:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Conv3D, BatchNormalization, Dropout, InputLayer


class ConvBlock(Layer):
  def __init__(self, filters=32, kernel_size = [3, 3, 3], 
               padding='same', activation='relu', dropout=0.1):
    super(ConvBlock, self).__init__()
    self.conv = Conv3D(filters=filters, 
                       kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                       activation=activation, 
                       padding=padding)
    self.norm = BatchNormalization()
    self.dropout = Dropout(dropout)

  def call(self, input, training=False):
    x = self.conv(input)
    x = self.norm(x)
    x = self.dropout(x, training=training)
    return x
  
  
model = Sequential()

model.add(InputLayer((96, 96, 96, 1)))
model.add(ConvBlock())

model.summary()
```

Hope this helps to improve it at least a little bit.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for replying! For #2, since the scores are from 1-5, should I just divide them all by 5 to scale them to [0, 1]? And for #3, what exactly is a wrapper and how is it better than the format I have? Sorry, I am quite new to deep learning and am not that knowledgeable. Perhaps there are some resources that you can send me as I could not find some myself. Thank you

Comment: for your first question, better to -1, and then /4, so it is strictly between 0 and 1. Wrapper just makes things shorter. It is a good thing to know as you can implement more sophisticated blocks such as skip connections with it. Check out [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers) tensorflow  guide.

Comment: Also, try higher learning rate, start with `1e-3` as `1e-6` seems too small.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the advices you gave, however they weren't able to solve the problem. Adding batchnormalization increased the range of the outputs  but the loss values stagnated. Higher learning rate gave out inaccurate outputs values of -500. Scaling the scores did not improve much since the outputs were still within a specific range instead of the entire spectrum. Decreasing dropout made my graphs slightly overfit. I have not tried the wrapper technique since I feel like it would take a considerable amount of time to learn and implement it without a certain degree of guarantee that it works